# Does Hunter's Mark provide bonus damage to both main hand and off hand attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger

Once the Ranger has marked a creature with *Hunter's Mark*, does she get to apply the extra 1d6 damage dice to both her main attack action and bonus off-hand attack?

The spell says:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack. (PHB pg.251)

The language used for *Two-weapon Fighting* says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. (PHB pg.195)

It seems like the off-hand attack is indeed an separate weapon attack, but just want to make sure I'm ruling and reading this correctly and not missing a legacy community consensus on the matter.

Answer (score 12):

The quote you've provided is pretty clear. Hunter's Mark deals an extra 1d6 damage *whenever* you hit the target with a weapon attack. So the off-hand attack will deal an extra 1d6, as will any additional attacks from Extra Attack, or any opportunity attacks you make on the target.